# Using AspectJ (ajc) compiler in Android Studio

Tags: compiler-construction, android-studio, aspectj

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821039/android-studio-and-monkeytalk) post talks about trying to swap to the ajc compiler in Android Studio, but it seems as though he never figured out a way of doing it. Has anyone else been able to figure this out?