# MonkeyTalk Causing VerifyException in Android Activity

Tags: android, monkeytalk

I'm trying to integrate MonkeyTalk automation into my pre-existing Android app that is built using gradle.

I followed the steps here: [Android Studio and MonkeyTalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821039/android-studio-and-monkeytalk/24720526#24720526) and got the demo app working, but when I run it in my own application I get the following crash on the second screen. Any idea why this happens?

This particular stack trace is using L preview targeting SDK 19, but I've also seen a similar (less detailed) stack trace on a Galaxy S4 with SDK 18 on it.

```
07-21 15:35:18.394  14642-14642/com.example.android.debug E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.debug, PID: 14642
    java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.example.android.activity.main.MainActivity because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'com.example.android.activity.main.MainActivity' appears in /data/app/com.example.android.debug-1.apk)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1062)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
```

Any idea what this means? I'm using Dagger for dependency injection, is that why it might not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the latest version of the monkeytalk and i guess your problem will not occur again.